# why active rigid body pass through passive

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have an animated object (passive rigid body), that touch another object (ball, active rigid body). Both have shapes "Mesh". But the passive rigid body doesn´t do anything to the active one. It pass through. Why?

Comment: Add images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ([read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post))

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have solved it. I modified the End frame of Rigid body Cache. As I added some other animations in the beggining, the original end frame was too short.